# How Do I Access receipt_url Using PHP From Stripe Paymentintent Response

Tags: php

Using the Stripe paymentintent sample pHP webhook code, I'm trying to access the receipt url to send to the customer.

How Do I Access `receipt_url` Using PHP From Stripe Paymentintent Response below?

```
StripePaymentIntent JSON: {
    "id": "pi_3M8p14IpsRT0wYssqwaR0IxyisnMd",
    "object": "payment_intent",
    "amount": 3400,
    "amount_capturable": 0,
    "amount_details": {
        "tip": []
    },
    "amount_received": 3400,
    "application": null,
    "application_fee_amount": null,
    "automatic_payment_methods": {
        "enabled": true
    },
    "canceled_at": null,
    "cancellation_reason": null,
    "capture_method": "automatic",
    "charges": {
        "object": "list",
        "data": [
            {
                "id": "ch_3M8p14sIpRT0wwYqwR00EadaoOH",
                "object": "charge",
                "amount": 3400,
                "amount_captured": 3400,
                "amount_refunded": 0,
                "application": null,
                "application_fee": null,
                "application_fee_amount": null,
                "balance_transaction": "txn_3M8dp14IpRT0swYqfwR0B1LhB6c",
                "billing_details": {
                    "address": {
                        "city": null,
                        "country": "US",
                        "line1": null,
                        "line2": null,
                        "postal_code": "11210",
                        "state": null
                    },
                    "email": null,
                    "name": null,
                    "phone": null
                },
                "calculated_statement_descriptor": "WWW.POBINSA.COM",
                "captured": true,
                "created": 1669571548,
                "currency": "usd",
                "customer": null,
                "description": null,
                "destination": null,
                "dispute": null,
                "disputed": false,
                "failure_balance_transaction": null,
                "failure_code": null,
                "failure_message": null,
                "fraud_details": [],
                "invoice": null,
                "livemode": false,
                "metadata": [],
                "on_behalf_of": null,
                "order": null,
                "outcome": {
                    "network_status": "approved_by_network",
                    "reason": null,
                    "risk_level": "normal",
                    "risk_score": 7,
                    "seller_message": "Payment complete.",
                    "type": "authorized"
                },
                "paid": true,
                "payment_intent": "pi_3M8p14IpdssRT0wdYqwR0IxyinMd",
                "payment_method": "pm_1M8p1skIpRT0dwYqwRcNWoUa4hp",
                "payment_method_details": {
                    "card": {
                        "brand": "visa",
                        "checks": {
                            "address_line1_check": null,
                            "address_postal_code_check": "pass",
                            "cvc_check": "pass"
                        },
                        "country": "US",
                        "exp_month": 1,
                        "exp_year": 2023,
                        "fingerprint": "hjsQpsxissss1K2s7DgsLqy",
                        "funding": "credit",
                        "installments": null,
                        "last4": "4242",
                        "mandate": null,
                        "network": "visa",
                        "three_d_secure": null,
                        "wallet": null
                    },
                    "type": "card"
                },
                "receipt_email": null,
                "receipt_number": null,
                "receipt_url": "https://pay.stripe.com/receipts/payment/CAcaaFwoVYWNjdFssssPMVBJcFsJUMHdsjhhdhgKN3HjpwGMgYDvNpxXfs6LBZ2QuWC4tMmD4KN4NHcZx7zNq-mWMtqyNeshdrX1iENJWZOr0-",
                "refunded": false,
                "refunds": {
                    "object": "list",
                    "data": [],
                    "has_more": false,
                    "total_count": 0,
                    "url": "/v1/charges/ch_3M8p14IpRT0wsYqwsR00EsaaosOH/refunds"
                },
                "review": null,
                "shipping": null,
                "source": null,
                "source_transfer": null,
                "statement_descriptor": null,
                "statement_descriptor_suffix": null,
                "status": "succeeded",
                "transfer_data": null,
                "transfer_group": null
            }
        ],
        "has_more": false,
        "total_count": 1,
        "url": "/v1/charges?payment_intent=pi_3M8p14IpRssT0wsYqswR0sIxyinMd"
    },
    "client_secret": "pi_3M8p14IpssRT0wYqwR0sIxssyinMd_secret_LHsoUs3jaLs5AaxOscGyHTz4Al54",
    "confirmation_method": "automatic",
    "created": 1669571506,
    "currency": "usd",
    "customer": null,
    "description": null,
    "invoice": null,
    "last_payment_error": null,
    "livemode": false,
    "metadata": [],
    "next_action": null,
    "on_behalf_of": null,
    "payment_method": "pm_1M8p1kIpsRT0wYqswRcNWssoU4hp",
    "payment_method_options": {
        "card": {
            "installments": null,
            "mandate_options": null,
            "network": null,
            "request_three_d_secure": "automatic"
        }
    },
    "payment_method_types": [
        "card"
    ],
    "processing": null,
    "receipt_email": null,
    "review": null,
    "setup_future_usage": null,
    "shipping": null,
    "source": null,
    "statement_descriptor": null,
    "statement_descriptor_suffix": null,
    "status": "succeeded",
    "transfer_data": null,
    "transfer_group": null
}
```

I Tried:

$receipt_url = $response["charges"]["data"]["receipt_url"];

Comment: $response->charges->data[0]->receipt_url;

Answer (score 0):

You have to told yourself that a Paymentintent could have multiple charges (but not really functional).

If your Stripe response is a JSON like you're showing, then you have to decode :

```
$response = json_decode($stripe_json_response,true);
```

If you decide not to had `true` at the end of the `json_decode`, then you have to look at the alternative I show you at the end.

---

**METHOD 1**

replace

```
$receipt_url = $response["charges"]["data"]["receipt_url"];
```

by

```
$receipt_url = $response["charges"]["data"][0]["receipt_url"];
```

because of you're able to have multiple charges. So you want the first one of the data array.

---

**METHOD 2**

If you know your charge id, just make a get charge retrieve request so you can have access to receipt url more easly :

```
$receipt_url = $response["receipt_url"];
```

---

**ALTERNATIVE**

Depending of your request. You can have access by an array :

```
$receipt_url = $response["receipt_url"];
$receipt_url = $response["charges"]["data"][0]["receipt_url"];
```

of by an object :

```
$receipt_url = $response->receipt_url;
$receipt_url = $response->charges->data[0]->receipt_url;
```